# How to group clusters

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I've used a simple similarity threshold approach to initially cluster similar text. I now want to group each of the clusters that are similar.

I'll try to break it down.

Cluster 1:

- Text
- Text
- Text

Cluster 2:

- Text
- Text

Both of these clusters talk about something fairly similar. How could I go about creating a "Group 1" that contains both of these clusters?

Answer (score 1):

If you use hierarchical clustering, it will also tell you how clusters merge until everything is connected.

With HAC, you have different choices of cluster similarity, such as single link and complete link.